# How to cast Pig field for AVG function

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, average

I am trying to use some Pig functions on [Titanic data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/campbwa/R-videos/master/train.csv). At one point I narrow it down to Passenger Class and Fare (Ticket price):

Here's the code:

```
sh echo "1. create FarePclass with two fields"
FarePclass   =  FOREACH train GENERATE Pclass,Fare ;
DUMP FarePclass;

sh echo "2. create FareByClass grouping by Pclass"
FareByPclass = GROUP FarePclass BY Pclass ;
--FareByPclass = GROUP FarePclass ALL;
--DUMP FareByPclass;

DESCRIBE FareByPclass;

sh echo "3. get average"
AvgFareByPclass = FOREACH FareByPclass GENERATE (float) SUM(FarePclass.Fare);
```

Here's some sample rows from the DUMP statement in step #1 and output:

```
(2,10.5)
(3,7.05)
(3,29.125)
(2,13)
(1,30)
(3,23.45)
(1,30)
(3,7.75)
2. create FareByClass grouping by Pclass
FareByPclass: {group: chararray,FarePclass: {(Pclass: chararray,Fare: chararray)}}
3. get average
2014-08-28 20:56:23,288 ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt: ERROR 1045: 
<file titanic_dypler_datafu.pig, line 36, column 56> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

I have this script and I'm trying to get the final line to run.
AvgFareByPclass = FOREACH FareByPclass GENERATE (float) SUM(FarePclass.Fare);

I get this error when trying to run it:
Cannot cast bag with schema :bag{:tuple(Fare:chararray)} to float.

Can you suggest how to cast FarePclass.Fare? Am I missing something conceptually about how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've already tried summing them is well too late to try to convert the chararray Fares into floating point numbers; they need to be numbers before you can take their sum.  Probably the most sensible place to do the conversion is in that first projection to FarePclass:

```
FarePclass   =  FOREACH train GENERATE Pclass,(float)Fare ;
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, that solved my problem. And in case anyone is wondering, the average ticket price paid for tickets on the Titanic, it is: First Class: $84.15  Second Class: $21.66 Third Class: $13.67. And BTW, my original goals was to compute the average, but I decided to get SUM to work first, in case you noticed the mismatch between names and function calls. Thanks again.